# Panads groupby and save certain columns to CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a CSV with columns Employer, City, State, Zipcode and Jobtitle to pandas.

The requirement is to group by Employer + City, count the results and write four columns (Employer, City, Zipcode and Count) to CSV.

Here is what I have done so far,

```
data = pd.read_csv("jobs.csv")
data.groupby(["Employer", "City"]).count()
```

This gives me:

```
Employer    City       State    Zipcode   Jobtitle 
Emp1      Cincinnati     1        1          1   
Emp2      Delaware      14        0         14   
Emp3      Akron          1        0          1
```

What I want is:

```
Employer    City       Zipcode    Jobcount
Emp1      Cincinnati    12345         1  
Emp2      Delaware      22112        14  
Emp3      Akron         34567         1
```

Where *Jobcount* shows the number of jobs for the combination of Employer + City.

Comment: 12345 is zip code.

Comment: Are you expecting 1 zipcode per city/employer?

Comment: Looks like you need `data.groupby(['Employer', 'City', 'Zipcode'])['Jobcount'].count()` .. as described in the duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.

data.groupby(['Employer', 'City', 'Zipcode'])['Jobcount'].count() gives error KeyError: 'Column not found: Jobcount'

Comment: Because the column in your df is Jobtitle

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting 1 zipcode per employee/city, you can do:

```
data.groupby(['Employer', 'City', 'Zipcode']).agg({'Jobtitle': 'size'})
data.columns = ['Employer', 'City', 'Zipcode', 'Jobcount']
```

Comment: This worked for me with a slight modification. Thanks.